# Can gimp rescale the workplace automatically?

Tags: gimp

I haven't found any solutions for this yet. My problem is this:

When I open an image with Gimp, the editor sets a fixed size for the image. For example, I open a 1920x1080 image with Gimp. Then the Borders are also set to that size. If I now import a 500x500 image, which is smaller,there is no problem.

[image]

But if I open the 500x500 image first, and then add a 1920x1080-image, that image gets cut off:

[image]

Is there a way, to tell Gimp that it needs to rescale the image to the largest layer that exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIMP has a menu entry just for that: Fit Canvas to Layers https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-image-resize-to-layers.html

Comment: Can I automate this? Like when I drop a larger image inside?